# How do I increase my Team Rank and what does it get me?

Tags: tree-of-savior

You have a Team rank that slowly gains experience and levels I assume by doing... things. What are the things you need to do and what are the benefits? I assume it involves the adventure journal stuff as well as Vibora and flat character/class experience. But there doesn't seem to be any indication anywhere besides the number gradually going up.

Answer (score 1):

The actual way the Team Rank increases hasn't been publicly disclosed, or if it has then (as of right now) is hard to find. What we do know however, is that it is impacted primarily by each character on your team and their level. Thus, the more characters you have and the higher level they are, the higher your team rank will be.

There are rumors that the "Team Experience" is calculated by taking each character's level, squaring it and then summing these. This has yet to confirmed nor do I know how much experience equals what level.

TL/DR: more characters at higher levels = higher team rank

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am hesitant to assign the bounty to it though. It is pretty much speculation (that is seemingly reasonable.) If you can find something more definite though I would reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be able to answer the part on how to increase the Team Rank but I what I can tell you is you'll get a 1% experience bonus when your Team Rank reaches level 2.

I just hit Team Rank level 2 three days ago.